# Let $\alpha$ be a $2$-cycle and $\beta$ be a $t$-cycle in $S_n$. Prove that $\alpha\beta\alpha$ is a $t$-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

$\bf Claim:$ Let $\alpha$ be a $2$-cycle and $\beta$ be a $t$-cycle in $S_n$.
Prove that $\alpha\beta\alpha$ is a $t$-cycle.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint, they commute and thus the product $\alpha\beta\alpha$ is equal to $\beta$, a $t$-cycle, but how would the proof proceed if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not disjoint?

Comment: Hint: What is the inverse of α?

Comment: Did you know that conjugation preserves cycle structure?

Comment: Exercise : If $g$ is a permutation in $S_n$, and $(a_1 \cdots a_k)$ is a $k$-cycle, show that $g(a_1 \cdots a_k)g^{-1} = (g(a_1) \cdots g(a_k))$

Comment: Thank you! This question seems much more trivial now.

Comment: Note this is an exercise in Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a different method to the one proposed in the comments.

**Edit:** As Dan Shved points out in his comment, the argument below shows that IF $\alpha\beta\alpha$ is a cycle, then it is a $t$-cycle; that is, it doesn't show why $\alpha\beta\alpha$ must be a cycle.

---

A $t$-cycle is a cycle $\beta$ such that the smallest $k > 0$ with $\beta^k = e$ is $k = t$, where $e$ the identity.

As $\alpha$ is a $2$-cycle, we have $$(\alpha\beta\alpha)^k = (\alpha\beta\alpha)(\alpha\beta\alpha)\dots(\alpha\beta\alpha) = \alpha\beta(\alpha\alpha)\beta(\alpha\alpha)\dots(\alpha\alpha)\beta\alpha = \alpha\beta\beta\dots\beta\alpha = \alpha\beta^k\alpha.$$

Now note that 
\begin{align*}
& \alpha\beta^k\alpha = e\\
\Leftrightarrow & \alpha\alpha\beta^k\alpha = \alpha\\
\Leftrightarrow & \beta^k\alpha = \alpha\\
\Leftrightarrow & \beta^k\alpha\alpha = \alpha\alpha\\
\Leftrightarrow & \beta^k = e.
\end{align*}

So the smallest value of $k > 0$ such that $(\alpha\beta\alpha)^k = e$ is also the smallest value of $k > 0$ such that $\beta^k = e$, which we know is $t$. Therefore $\alpha\beta\alpha$ is a $t$-cycle.

Comment: This is a neat proof. Thanks!

Comment: What this proves is that *if* $\alpha \beta \alpha$ is a cycle, then it is a $t$-cycle. There is still the hypothetical possibility that $\alpha \beta \alpha$ is not a cycle at all.

Comment: How do we address this fact and make the proof complete? @DanShved

Comment: Josh B.'s and Easy's hints are the solution. One should note that $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha$, therefore $\alpha \beta \alpha$ = $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}$, so $\alpha \beta \alpha$ is a conjugate of $\beta$, and conjugation preserves cycle structure.